# VBA Get the number of the column that contains a specific value

Tags: vba

Hello I am trying to get a number of the column that contains the value "#" in row 1. The code I have written is:

```
Dim ColumnNumber_Number As single
ColumnNumber_Number = Cells(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BOM").Cells(1, Cells.Find("#", lookat:=xlWhole).Column)).Column
```

E.G. That column is number 2 and I need to get that value into my variable
But it returns an error "Invalid procedure call or argument". What's the mistake I'm making?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood your question (to return the column in discussion searching in the first row), the next code will do what you need:

```
  Dim ColumnNumber_Number As Long, wsB As Worksheet
  Set wsB = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BOM")
  ColumnNumber_Number = wsB.rows(1).Find("#", lookat:=xlWhole).Column
```

Your construction is not working because of a strange construction. First `Cells(` does not have any meaning, and searching in all the sheet cells is not the most appropriate way, I think. No nice to construct a new cell to return the column from this one, too... Anyhow, the cells where to search for should be fully qualified.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and an actual explanation of the mistake

Answer (score 1):

What about this? You don't have to give a search range that way

```
Sub test_macro()

    Set ColumnNumber_Number = Cells.Find(What:="#", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
             :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
                        False)
 
 If Not ColumnNumber_Number Is Nothing Then
 MsgBox ColumnNumber_Number.Column
 End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't understand the mistake I am making and I prefer to not set any ranges liek in your answer ``Range("A:F").Find("#")``